# Store an object in current request

Tags: java, performance, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.5 with Java. I have to retrieve some data from a very slow database and need this data in several parts of my application, especially within my Java controllers and the Scala templates.

It would be very "messy" to carry my data object to every method as a parameter.

What I want is to retrieve the data from the database, "bind" it to the current request and use it in my controllers and templates. 
It should survive one single HTTP request. A parallel HTTP request should re-load the data from the database. But I do not want to load the same data twice within the same request.

What is the correct place to store my data with Play?

Currently I am using a helper method like "Helper.getHeavyObject()" within my Controllers and within the templates. This helper retrieves the data from a Redis cache, but I want to get rid of that. That is too much overhead. Currently I am loading the same object up to 6 times from Redis for a single request. There must be a better way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Http has a `public Map<String, Object> args;` and you can access it on the templates and the controllers like this `ctx().args.put("your_key", object)`. It is available on during only one request.

Keep in mind that play is stateless and maybe try to use play cache
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache

Or you could create a action composition to on every request read the cache and place the value on the map or simply request from your cache server.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition

Comment: >Http has a public Map<String, Object> args; and you can access it on the templates and the controllers
Perfect, I will try that. This is what I was looking for.


>try to use play cache
Currently I am using a Redis Cache and I am querying it up to 6 times for the same object which is ridiculous.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you use action composition you can add the value on the map but keep in mind that on EVERY new request it will do the query and add it to the map due to play's stateless design.